# Where is left recursion in this little CF grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers, left-recursion

```
S → D
D → E | EC
E → anyId
C → B | .D | B.D
B → <S> | <SA>
A → ,S | ,SA
```

The tool I am using keeps complaining about left recursion in this grammar. I can't see where.

The language recognized is something like:

```
anyId
anyId.anyId
anyId<anyId>
anyId<anyId>.anyId<anyId,anyId>
```

Comment: Did you specify the start symbol correctly? Try also to get rid of unit productions.

Comment: What tool are you using? That grammar is not left-recursive afaics but it isn't LL(k) either.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In fact, this grammar looks the way it looks because I was trying to be "as much literally faithful as possible" to a non-LL(*) informal specification. I will follow your hint and just implement the requirements in a more "natural" way.